# Enviar datos adicionales al value en select (react)

Tags: reactjs

Tengo un `select` que funciona bien pero quiero aparte del value enviar un dato adicional llamado "descripción" pero no sé cómo.

```
<div className="col-lg-4">
    <div className="row mx-auto mb-3">
        <label className="p-0 my-auto col-sm-6 col-form-label">PROMO CODE</label>
        <select onChange={(e) => this.changePromo(e)} className="form-control form-control-sm">
             <option value={this.state.promocode}>{this.state.lng["0"]["IndividualReservation"]["btnTab"]}</option>
             {this.state.PromoData.map((code) =>
                 <option key={code.idconf_promocode} value={code.promocode_name} descripcion={code.descripcion}>{code.promocode_name} </option>)
             }
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ese es el select y así trato de enviarlo, pero no llega a mi función

```
changePromo = (e) => {
    this.state.resevaDirecta.promocode = e.target.value;
    this.state.resevaDirecta.descPromocode = e.target.descripcion;
}
```

El value llega perfectamente, pero *descripcion* no está llegando.

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En primer lugar: cada elemento HTML tiene una colección propia de atributos; para crear un atributo personalizado como `descripcion` que sea válido en HTML5 debes especificarlo con el prefijo `data-` (consulta esta página: [uso de atributos de datos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/HTML/como/Usando_atributos_de_datos)):

```
<option key={code.idconf_promocode} value={code.promocode_name} data-descripcion={code.descripcion}>{code.promocode_name}</option>
```

Para usarlo en tu función ([React - No modifiques el estado directamente](https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)):

```
changePromo(e) {
    // dataset es el objeto que contiene los atributos "data-"
    const { value, dataset } = e.target;

    /* Cambios en el estado deben darse por setState.
       Revisa las secciones "No modifiques el estado directamente" y
       "Las actualizaciones del estado pueden ser asíncronas" en la 
       documentación de React.
    */
    this.setState(prevState => {
        let { resevaDirecta } = prevState;
        resevaDirecta.promocode: value;
        resevaDirecta.descPromocode = dataset.descripcion;

        return { reservaDirecta };
    });
}
```

En segundo lugar: si el dato de la descripción viene de la misma colección desde donde originaste la lista de opciones, puedes utilizar ese mismo *origen* para obtener el valor que quieres:

```
<option key={code.idconf_promocode} value={code.promocode_name}>{code.promocode_name}</option>
```

Función:

```
changePromo(e) {
    const { value } = e.target,
          descripcion = this.state.PromoData.find(obj => obj.promocode_name === value).descripcion;

    this.setState(prevState => {
        let { resevaDirecta } = prevState;
        resevaDirecta.promocode: value;
        resevaDirecta.descPromocode = descripcion;

        return { reservaDirecta };
    });
}
```